# How to let a View fill the remaining space?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a layout with tho views, A and B,

```
___
|A|
|B|
---
```

A can have very varying height. I want B to have ParentHeight-A.height, and would like to this via xml (I know I can resize them programmatically, but hope to avoid it).

How can I achieve this with the Android layout system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout` and set B's `layout_weight` property to 1. It will occupy all the space that is left after A occupies the space it needs.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely basic layout stuff.  I suggest you read up about `LinearLayout` and width/height specifications.  Generally speaking, your layout will be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View android:id="@+id/A
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View android:id="@+id/B
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```